# Android Layout with buttons and check boxes

Tags: android, layout

Have a minor formatting problem. Any help appreciated! Currently I am displaying this:

[image]

But I want this:

[image]

(Sorry for the small images, something is messing up when I try to add them)
I'm guessing I need to do another linear or relative layout but had no success in trying...

The XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/startLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/start"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/versionNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|start"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/fastfieldlogo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/devMode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/orangedark"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="DEVELOPMENT MODE" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/button_login"
            android:text="Login" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/workOfflineSSO"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Work Offline" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/resetCookieSSO"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="Reset Cookies" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `LinearLayout` width `wrap_content` and use `layout_gravity` instead of `gravity`. Finally remove gravity from the check boxes like below.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/button_login"
        android:text="Login" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/workOfflineSSO"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Work Offline" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/resetCookieSSO"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="Reset Cookies" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Perfect. Looks like the, android:layout_width="wrap_content" was the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add your checkboxes to a LinearLayout with vertical orientation and align them to the start and left (gravity="start").